# What is the best way to save/load img/file(word,excel etc.) in php/asp.net application?

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm currently a student and I aspire to become a great web developer :)

I want to work on some 'practice' projects that is capable of storing/retrieving images or any  type of file(.doc,.xcl,.txt, etc.). Some are saying that it's better to store img/any file in a file system as opposed to saving it inside the database.

I would like to know the pros and cons of both side.

I would also like to know what's the best data type for storing imgs/files in MySQL
(I'm currently using longblob for PHP-MySQL)*For saving imgs*

I would also like to know what's the best data type for storing imgs/files in SQL Server
(I'm currently using Asp.net Varbinary(max) for SQL Server 2008)*For saving imgs*

Lastly,I'm just curious on how websites like facebook and other big web applications store imgs and files.

Sir/Ma'am, your answers would be of great help and be very much appreciated. Thank you++

Comment: `Some are saying that it's better to store img/any file in a file system as opposed to saving it inside the database.` Have you considered this solution? IMHO best way to store files in sql databases is not to store them in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pros:** Storing in database

- Files are saved "forever"
- Can restrict access to the real file more easily
- You can, technically, check for duplicate files.
- You are not keeping the files on drive, so it can be faster to access for the server
- Less files on your server is considered "better" and more organized
- "one file for everything"

**Cons:**

- If site is up but database is not, file will be invalid (through "direct" linking)
- Some databases that cannot be reconfigured only allow blobs to be of a certain size limit (a few mb), therefore making it so that really large images cannot be stored (but can be separated)
- More data becomes stored in memory when loading file to (to a variable); similar to the problem above, very large images can slow down your server.
- Some files may be of different character encoding, and thus storing and/or retrieving files may corrupt the original file. I am not sure if this is real problem, but I think it was.

I personally suggest you to  do not store files on my database anymore because of the cons.

Comment: `You are not keeping the files on drive, so it can be faster to access for the server` - heresy. Database is located in the files on the hard drive, and server can not access it directly, so accessing it is much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses haystack for images.

Here is a link from their site describing image storage and retrieval

http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919

Based on prior experience, I would recommend not storing files directly into a SQL database.